# Comparing an list of array and selected value and displaying it in tableview cell based on index

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have an application wherein when tableview cell is clicked, another tableview is loaded and an api call is made. Based on the response from api, table view list is loaded and when a particular item in the second tableview is selected, there is a selected checkbox displayed just besides the tableview text label and at the same time database is updated with selected value,
so when I come back to the first tableview I display a label with selected item.

When the first tableview cell I clicked, api is called and results of api should be compared with the active list from database and that particular cell should remain selected.

When there is some item selected in first tableview and when i click on that particular cell, api results reload the tableview and selection for respective cell is not displayed.

Following is the code:

```
 for selectedDict in (appDelegate?.selectedCategoryFilterArray)! {
                let selectedUuid = selectedDict.categoryUuid
                print("selectedUuid\(selectedUuid)")

                for allDict in self.requestedFiltersArray!{

                    let allUuid = allDict.objectForKey("uuid") as? String
                    if selectedUuid == allUuid {
                         cell.imgSelected.image = UIImage(named: "radio_selected")
                        continue
                    }else{
                        cell.imgSelected.image = UIImage(named: "radio")

                    }
                    print("allUuid\(allUuid)")
                }
            }
```

This is not working as expected, no cell is displaying as selected even if their is  a cell selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you placed this code?

From what I think you might be trying to achieve, here is an approach that I would suggest.

For your second tableView which is loaded based on the API call results, I would add a String property called uuid to your custom UITableViewCell class.

Then when you call cellForRowAtIndexPath to populate your second tableView, instantiate each cell as your custom UITableViewCell and set its uuid property to the appropriate value based on the results array, using the indexPath.row.

After setting that, next you can run the for loop with your condition to match the cell's uuid property value against the selectedUuid value from your AppDelegate and thereafter set the image as per the logic.

A rough implementation:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier") as! YourCustomTableViewCell

        let allDict = self.requestedFiltersArray[indexPath.row]
        let allUuid = allDict.objectForKey("uuid") as? String

        cell.uuid = allUuid

        for selectedDict in (appDelegate?.selectedCategoryFilterArray)! {
            let selectedUuid = selectedDict.categoryUuid
            if selectedUuid = cell.uuid {
                cell.imageSelected.image = UIImage(named: "radio_selected")
            } else {
                cell.imageSelected.image = UIImage(named: "radio")
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked with a small change. Have to add a break inside the if condition.